# React update list isn't a function

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I would like to update the `chatList`, when the user presses a button the method `newChat()` is called and an API is invoked. This API sends back all the old chats + the new chats. But when I call this I get an error that `TypeError: chatList.map is not a function`. Is the error because I am adding back the complete chats?
How can I make chatList update itself when I pressed the button, I tried something once with the UseEffect, however this did not work either.

So how can I make that when the button is pressed the old and the new chats are displayed in the list.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GroupchatCard } from "./GroupchatCard";
import ChatEmpty from "./ChatEmpty";
import axios from "axios";
function ChatSide() {


  const [lengthChats, setLengthChats] = useState(0);
  const [isChatEmpty, setIsChatEmpty] = useState(true);
  const [chatList, setChatList] = useState([]);

  const [messagesnumber, setMessagesnumber] = useState("");
  const getMessagesnumber = () => {
    var zuffalszahl = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    setMessagesnumber(zuffalszahl);
  };
  // This should load all the chats inital at the beginning
  useEffect(() => {
 
     getChats();
    
  }, []);

   const getChats = () => {
    axios
    .get("http://localhost:4000/chat/rooms", { } )
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        if(res.data.length >= 1) {
          setLengthChats(res.data.length)
          setChatList(...chatList, res.data)
          setIsChatEmpty(false);
          localStorage.removeItem('chatList')
          localStorage.setItem('chatList', JSON.stringify(res.data))
        }
        
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
   }
   
  // If user clicked on the plus add all chats again to the list
 useEffect(() => {
 
    // Check if some chats are saved in the local storage
     if(lengthChats > 1) {
     console.log("working only if the button is clicked")
     }
    
  }, [lengthChats]);
  /**
   * Gernate a new Chat
   */
  const newChat = () => {
    console.log(lengthChats)
    if (lengthChats < 3) {
      axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/chat/add", { } )
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log(res.data)
          if(res.data.length >= 1) {

            setLengthChats(res.data.length)
            setChatList(...chatList, res.data)
            setIsChatEmpty(false);
            localStorage.removeItem('chatList')
            localStorage.setItem('chatList', JSON.stringify(res.data))
          }
          
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    else {
      window.alert("Du kannst nur maximal drei Chats offen haben");
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", getMessagesnumber);
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="row m-1 mb-5 h-100" style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
        <div class="col-md-11" >
          Chats
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" onClick={newChat}>
          <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" style={{ fontSize: "2rem", color: "#5869ff" }}></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mb-2">

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {
            isChatEmpty === true &&
            <ChatEmpty></ChatEmpty>
          }
          {
            isChatEmpty === false &&
            <div className="list-group">

              {chatList.map((d, i) => (
                <GroupchatCard messagesnumber={messagesnumber} chatname={d.chatname} chatid={d.id} chatimage={d.image} />
              ))
              }

            </div>
          }


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChatSide;
```

I found out that it is because of this `useEffect`. But how else could I say when the component is loaded for the first time do this inital commit so we have all the values and if the user clicks a button don't consider this `useEffect` anymore.

```
  useEffect(() => {
 
     getChats();
    
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the chatlist to be an array:

```
setChatList(prevList => [...prevList, ...res.data])
```

It accepts a function will pass the current chats, and now you just have to wrap with [].

```
setChatList(...chatList, res.data)  // This fails
```

This passes each item in the array as parameter (the `...`). So the first item will be selected, since the first parameter will be set to the value. This not an array (only the item), so .map fails

Comment: Thank you I still found out that it is because of the useEffect with the initial loading. I commented out the method and it worked.

Comment: Yes because you are not loading the initial chat data from the api. So there is nothing to fail. But for the code to work, you need to change the code to pass an array.

Comment: The problem is, when I write it like this `setChatList(prevList => [...prevList, res.data])`, the map function is empty. The values are transferred empty. :/

Comment: This seems to be connected to a different problem connected to the api call and not the react code here. Can you console.log the values and see what is returned? If res.data is an array, you also need to spread it: [...prev, ...res.data])

Comment: Yes, sure it looks like this `[{chatname: "hello", id: 2}, {chatname: "agian", id: 3}]`

Answer (score 1):

First guess would be that chatList is not considered an array anymore.

Maybe adding the following before the chatList.map would help you see what's going wrong

```
console.log(chatList)
console.log(typeof(chatList))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using
setChatList(...chatList, res.data)
please try to set chatList as shown below:
setChatList([...chatList, ...res.data]);

Comment: The problem is that the old element occurs twice. How can I get around this?